# How to limit the keypair generated by keystore to a specific app

Tags: android, keystore

In a jar file, I have generated a keypair using keystore and with public key I'm encrypting the string and using private key I am able to decrypt the string. 
Using this jar file, I have implemented a apk and its working fine. Since the keys are stored in a device memory, I want to make sure no other apps can use these keys from memory so that the data will not be decrypted other than original app.

here's my sample code:

*to generating keypair:*

```
KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
generator.initialize(spec);
KeyPair keyPair = generator.generateKeyPair();
```

*for retrieving publickey:*

```
KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry)keyStore.getEntry(alias, null);
RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) privateKeyEntry.getCertificate().getPublicKey();
```

*for retrieving privatekey:*

```
KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry)keyStore.getEntry(alias, null);
Cipher output = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
output.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKeyEntry.getPrivateKey());
```

How to make sure these public and private keys should be used only for my app and no other app can get access to these keys?

Answer (score 1):

You app's Android Keystore keys are only accessible from your app. See https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html#WhichShouldIUse